# Unable to load image RGB table from a file (Lua)

Tags: image, lua

I been trying to implement images into a program window i made in lua what i basically do is get all RGB info of the image and draw it on a canvas as all scripts are stored online and called using `LuaSocket` it increases the virtual usage  of my server alot so i am trying to save the image RGB data into a text file and load it and make the image on canvas but unable to do it , it just creates a blank image with no RGB info on it here is what i am doing

this is my small part (example) of the rgb table of a image

```
Flower = {}
Flower[1] = {}
Flower[1][1] = 16446446
Flower[1][2] = 3552822
Flower[1][3] = 3552822
Flower[1][4] = 3552822
Flower[1][5] = 3552822
Flower[1][6] = 3552822
Flower[1][7] = 3552822
Flower[1][8] = 3552822
Flower[1][9] = 3552822
Flower[1][10] = 3552822
Flower[1][11] = 3552822
Flower[1][12] = 3552822
Flower[1][13] = 3552822
Flower[1][14] = 3552822
Flower[1][15] = 3552822
Flower[1][16] = 3552822
Flower[1][17] = 3552822
Flower[1][18] = 3552822
Flower[1][19] = 3552822
Flower[1][20] = 3552822
Flower[1][21] = 3552822
Flower[1][22] = 3552822
Flower[1][23] = 3552822
Flower[1][24] = 3552822
```

its really huge and ends at

```
Flower[448][235] = 16446446
```

so what i do in my program is

```
local f = assert(io.open(MyPath.."log.txt", "r"))
content = f:read("*all")
f:close()
return content

Form = createForm(true)
Form.width = 447
Form.height = 234
image = createImage(Form);
image_stretch(image, true);
image.width = 447
image.height = 234
image.top = -10
image.left = -10

setProperty(image, 'Anchors','akTop,akLeft,akRight,akBottom');
canvas = image.getCanvas();
brush = canvas.getBrush();
brush.Color = 0xF0F0F0;
canvas.fillRect(canvas, 0, 0, Form.width, Form.width);
pen = canvas.getPen();
pen.width = 2;
pen.Color = 0x000000;
for i,table in pairs(Flower) do
   for _,color in pairs(Flower[i]) do
      canvas_setPixel(canvas, i + 5   , _ + 5, color)
   end
end
```

Comment: Why not save/load images as actual images rather than Lua tables? They'll be much smaller, even without compression. Also, where are you parsing your file?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo i have some reasons thats why i am using lua tables to get my image Rgb n make image i am using Lua engine of Cheat Engine 6.4 and it doesnt have any command like Load/Save image .. thats why i need help on it

Answer (score 0):

Well i sorted it and got the answer instead of Opening the file using `io.open` i directly execute the file by using `dofile`

so instead of

```
local f = assert(io.open(MyPath.."log.txt", "r"))
content = f:read("*all")
f:close()
return content
```

did

```
dofile(MyPath.."log.txt", "r")
```

and it worked perfectly